# After enabling spell checking with Squiggly the delete key and arrow keys stop working

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, squiggly

After enabling Squiggly on a TextFlow the delete key and arrow keys stop working. If I click around or switch applications and switch back it sometimes starts to work again. If I do not use Squiggly at all the delete and arrow keys work as expected.

Here is the code I'm using to enable Squiggly:

```
var locale:String = "en_US";
SpellUIForTLF.enableSpelling(myTextFlow, locale);
```

Has anyone encountered this and is there a fix?

Comment: Did you have a question in mind?

Comment: Naw. I like posting random things online. Did you know that the sea otter has over one million hairs per inch of skin? The human has around 100 hairs per inch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug with TLF or the SpellUIForTLF class. In SpellUIForTLF class there is a method, "doSpellingJob" that is called. It is after this call that you want reselect the selection in the textflow.

```
    // From customized SpellUIForTLF.as class
    public function doSpellingJob():void
    {
        if (_spellingEnabled == false) return;

        hh.clearSquiggles();
        for (var idx:int = 0; idx < mTextFlow.flowComposer.numControllers; idx++)
        {
            var testController:ContainerController = mTextFlow.flowComposer.getControllerAt(idx); 
            //if (getValidFirstWordIndexTLF(testController) != -1) 
                spellCheckRangeTLF(getValidFirstWordIndexTLF(testController), getValidLastWordIndexTLF(testController));
        }

        if (hasEventListener(Event.COMPLETE)) {
            dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
        }


        if (keepFocusOnTextFlow && !calledSetFocusOnce) {
            setFocusOnTextFlowContainer();
            calledSetFocusOnce = true;
        }
    }

    public function setFocusOnTextFlowContainer():void {
        //trace("Setting focus on textflow");
        var testController:ContainerController;

        if (mTextFlow.flowComposer) {
            if (mTextFlow.flowComposer.numControllers) {
                testController = mTextFlow.flowComposer.getControllerAt(0);
            }
        }

        FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.stage.focus = null;

        if (testController) {
            FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.stage.focus = testController.container;
        }

        if (mTextFlow.interactionManager) {
            //mTextFlow.flowComposer.updateAllControllers();
            mTextFlow.interactionManager.setFocus();
            var selectionState:SelectionState = mTextFlow.interactionManager.getSelectionState();
            //TextObject(currentObject).textFlow.interactionManager.clearSelection();
            mTextFlow.interactionManager.selectRange(selectionState.anchorPosition, selectionState.activePosition);
        }
    } 


    /**
     * Sets the focus on the first container controller on the first composition complete.
     * This is to fix a bug in some situations where the delete and arrow keys do not 
     * work after spell checking has been enabled before the text flow composition 
     * has completed. Usually there is also a delay with editing the first time the dictionary loads. 
     * */
    public static var keepFocusOnTextFlow:Boolean;
    public static var calledSetFocusOnce:Boolean;

    public function SpellUIForTLF(textModel:TextFlow, lang:String)
    {       

        ...
        calledSetFocusOnce = false;

        if (keepFocusOnTextFlow) {
            setFocusOnTextFlowContainer();
        }

        ...
    }
```